# Consuming SOAP and REST Service in Android Application

Tags: android, web-services

I have tried to create a sample application for consuming SOAP and REST based services. 
When I tried to do the app for consuming SAOP services using KSOAP 2 API I was getting *"The Operation Timed out"* as a response.

When I tried an app for consuming REST services, it works fine for local services, but if I tried to connect internet services I am getting *"The Operation Timed out"* as a response too.

I thought proxy is the problem, so I configured proxy settings in the emulator and I can access the services through browsers in the emulator now.

Any suggestion or help please.

Comment: Please produce some code samples so we can see what you're trying that's not working.

Comment: http://paste.org/50479 Here I have posted my code to consume the service

Comment: try testing it in an environment without proxy, maybe as you mentioned that could be the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you able to access web service in browser in emulator then you can access in android app.

I saw your code just replace the line `String result= androidHttpTransport.responseDump;`

by `SoapObject soapresult = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;`
and add this line `String result = soapresult.getProperty(0).toString();`

if you still have any problem then write me.

Comment: But when the call made to server I do not get any response , the flow straight away going in to catch block, since the `HTTP TRANSPORT` call  throwing the **Operation Timed out** exception.

Comment: are you able to access that web service in web browser

Comment: are you added Internet permission in android manifest file.i.e `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>`

Comment: Thats the first thing I done when started this application dude\

Comment: actually I want some info about your code if you don't mind.Can you tell me the `minSdkVersion` of your application specify in manifest file.

Comment: I even tried to access the service URL with My Credentials for access through proxy, but didn't help .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12483/discussion-between-arunpandiyan-murugesan-and-sachin-d)